# Working with user type does not work in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a user type in Django with that idea the user have the first type he will be redirected to a template if he is another he will be redirected to another one

this is my models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('paitent', 'paitent'), ('Doctor', 'Doctor'), ('reception', 'reception'), ('temporary', 'temporary'))
    STATUS_CHOICES_2 = (('yes', 'yes'), ('no', 'no'))
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='paitent')
    allowd_to_take_appointement = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES_2, default='yes')

    def is_doctor(self):
        if self.type_of_user == 'Doctor':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_paitent(self):
        if self.type_of_user == 'paitent':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_reception(self):
        if self.type_of_user == 'reception':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_temporary(self):
        if self.type_of_user == 'temporary':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

and this is my views.py

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    
    if User.is_doctor:
        return render(request, 'user/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'user/dashboard2.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

but it always takes me to the dashboard .html only event if I change the user type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.is_doctor` asks for the function on the class, which always exists, so it’s always true.

What you want is to test the `user` object :

```py
if request.user.is_doctor():
```

You could also use `@property` in front of your `is_functions` to get rid of using parenthesis, i.e. `request.user.is_doctor`.

Beware, you also have a typo on `is_patient`/`is_paitent`

Suggestion: you could simplify a code like :

```py
if a_very_complicated_test:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

with

```py
return a_very_complicated_test
```